# ECONNRESET error when accessing Ruby application which runs in Webrick

Tags: ruby, centos7, redmine, webrick

I am trying to install redmine (bugtracker which runs on ruby). I use webrick, it starts all fine, but when I access http://IP:3000/, it throws the following error  in the server logs and the page does not load in the browser.

```
ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:11
    /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `eof?'
    /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:82:in `run'
    /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
```

I am a bit stuck here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was due to the port 3000 was being blocked by the network where the server was part of. Once the port block was removed, it started to work. Thanks @mike-k for your tips.

Comment: How did you remove the port block?